# How to enable syntax highlighting for *.handlebars files within Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, editor, handlebars.js

The broader question might be "Can you associate existing syntax highlighting (e.g. *.html) with arbitrary file extensions (e.g. *.handlebars) within Visual Studio 2012?"

I know there is an extension which allows highlighting of handlebars templates within *.html files, however I require the naming convention of *.handlebars for precompilation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Under <kbd>Visual Studio</kbd> -> <kbd>Tools</kbd> -> <kbd>Options</kbd> you can set the type of editor for each extension:

[image: Set the extension editor]

I have the following features installed, not sure which one acctually installs  the Javascript Editor:

- The Visual Studio Web Developer Tools (out of the box feature)
  [image: Web Developer Tools]
- [The ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1](http://www.asp.net/downloads)
- [Visual Studio 2012 Extensions for the Windows Library for Javascript](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30687)
- [WebEssentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6)
- And of course [Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305)

Comment: Curious how you have "JavaScript Editor" as an option - I'm running VS2012 and I don't have that in my list. Was that an extension?

Comment: Added links to installed extensions and features. Not sure if they matter.

Answer (score 3):

I totally agree with @jessehouwing but instead of choosing "Javascript Editor" simply choose "Html Editor". The problem is that if you're using a framework like EmberJS VS still won't recognize the syntax.

For instance:

```
<a href="#" class="deletelist" {{action "deleteTodoList" todoListId}}>X</a>
```

The action won't be recognized as valid syntax.